# BeagleBoard Narcissus ToolChain with OpenCv issue

Tags: linux, opencv, beagleboard, linux-toolchain

I'm using Eclipse with Narcissus Cross-Compiler Toolchain to compile OpenCV project on my BeagleBoard-XM.
I followed those links to do this:
http://www.lvr.com/eclipse1.htm
http://groups.google.com/group/beagleboard/browse_thread/thread/1ec0c6585a2141c8?pli=1

When i try to compile the project i get an Error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [hello_world.o] Error 1   hello_world         C/C++ Problem
```

I think the problem is with the Toolchain itself, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The CDT framework runs GNU Make under the hood to do the actual build (unless you are using the internal builder, which isn't the default). The error you see is because one of the makefile targets, of the managed project's auto-generated makefile, has failed to run successfully.

The output of the **Problem** view is insufficient information to answer your question. Only the **Console** view output for the build contains sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please post the entire output of the **CDT Build Console** for the **Console** view.

At this point the only guess we can make is that something in the build process exited with exit code 1.